# LightDM running command after authenticating (pam_exec or other)

Tags: pam, lightdm, autostart

LightDM allows using `dm-tool lock` to "lock" the session. But I can't find config responsible for authenticating in `/etc/pam.d`.

- `/etc/pam.d/lightdm` - is only during initial login to session
- `/etc/pam.d/lightdm-greeter` - works during greeter loading, but before authenticating

I want to run some command every time after LighDM authentication even after `dm-tool lock`.

`pam_exec.so` seemed promising but I can't find the right config. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, my fault, things I missed

- LighDM uses **auth** class from `/etc/pam.d/lightdm`
- Full path of executable has to be specified in pam_exec